# Is it possible to change marker properties form a figure made with 'plot' returned from a function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Let's say I have the function

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def dofig(x,y):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    A = ax.plot(x,y,'o-' , markersize=5)
    return fig, ax, A

fig, ax, A = dofig(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
```

Is there a way to change the marker size or other attributes of the returned figure made using `plt.plot()`?

Why the list of attributes of `scatter` is much larger than `plot`?

This is an edited question. I thanks the comments, and just wonder if there is some trick to do that.

Comment: You can get the data that's been ploted by looking at the ax children, and then getting info such as _x and _y, and then replot... but that kind of beats the point of using a function for plotting in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call to `ax.set_sizes(sizes)` where "sizes" is a list the length of your points which vales are equal to the size you want those points to be:

Default Graph

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

scatter = plt.scatter(x,y,s=50)
```

[image]

Updated marker size:

```
scatter = plt.scatter(x,y,s=50)

sizes = [300]*len(x)
scatter.set_sizes(sizes)
```

[image]

Comment: I liked the trick ' [300]*len(x) '.  Creating the figure and returning the scatter object, it doesn't work (the marks don't change the size. And trying the 'ax.set_sizes(...)' , I got the error "AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_sizes'"